# C# 3.5 partial class String IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Tags: c#, .net, string, .net-3.5

I'm trying to create extra functionality to the `String` class (`IsNullOrWhitespace` as in .NET4 )
But I'm having an problem with referencing:

> Error 1   'String' is an ambiguous reference between 'string' and 'geolis_export.Classes.String'

I don't want to create an extension method. Because this will crash if `string x = null;`

Usage:

```
private void tbCabineNum_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !e.Text.All(Char.IsNumber) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Text);
}
```

String partial:

```
public partial class String
{
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value)
    {
        if (value == null) return true;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim());
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to create extras for the `String` class?
I have tried to put the partial in the `System` namespace, but this gives other errors.

Renaming `String` to `String2` fixes the problem also. But this is not what I want, because then there is no reference with the original `String` class.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is not possible like this, because the `string` class in the .NET framework is not partial.
Instead, use a real extension method like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string value)
    {
        if (value == null) return true;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim());
    }
}
```

The usage would then be like this:

```
string s = "test";
if(s.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
    // s is null or whitespace
```

As with all extension methods, the call will not result in a null reference exception if the string is `null`:

```
string s = null;
if(s.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()) // no exception here
    // s is null or whitespace
```

The reason for this behavior is that the compiler will translate this code into IL code that is equivalent to the IL code of the following:

```
string s = null;
if(StringExtensions.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    // s is null or whitespace
```

Comment: @Stinus: Right, you were missing that extension methods must live in a `static` class and have only `static` methods. They also must accept a `this String` parameter as the first argument to the method (assuming you're extending `String`).

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning true if the string is null?

Comment: @Stinus: No, it will not. See the last part of my answer. @Chris: Yes, you are right, I just copied that part from the OPs code. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

An extension method has to be defined as a *static method* inside a *static class.* Also notice the `this` keyword on the parameter.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullorWhitespace(this string input)
    {
         // perform logic
    }
}
```

What you have done by omitting the `static` on the class is define a competing class within your assembly, hence the ambiguous message from the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The `string` class is not declared as partial, you will have to write an extension method instead.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how you create an extension method. The class isn't a partial, it needs to be a static class and it can be named anything (MyExtensionMethods). You also need to mark your parameter with "this" on an extension method.

Try this instead

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string value)
    {
        if (value == null) return true;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an extension method, you need to use the following syntax. (Note the use of the keyword `this`):

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trimming the string results in an avoidable string allocation (which can hurt performance). Better to check each character in turn and not allocate anything:

```cs
        public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string value)
        {
#if NET35
            if (value == null)
                return true;

            foreach (var c in value)
            {
                if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
#else
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value);
#endif
        }
```

The `#if NET35` code means that the fallback implementation exists only when targeting .NET 3.5. You can adjust that comparison to meet your project's target frameworks as needed. Otherwise, the default `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` method is used, and this util method would likely be inlined.